# Python: ctypes and Pointer to Structure

Tags: python, pointers, structure, ctypes

I am trying to make a pointer of a struct and then de-reference it. But it's crashing. I have mimic'ed the behvior here with this simple code.

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes

class File(Structure):
 _fields_ = [("fileSize", c_uint),
            ("fileName", c_byte * 32)]

f = File()
f.fileSize = 2
print(f.fileSize)
P = ctypes.POINTER(File)
p = P.from_address(addressof(f))
print(p.contents.fileSize)
```

Can someone point out what's the issue with this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `File.from_address(addressof(f))` would work. Hopefully this helps you see the mistake you made. `P.from_address` creates a pointer whose value is the data at the target address. Given you have the type already, what you want is simply `ptr = P(f)`. There's no need to use `pointer`, which will just take the long way around to `P(f)` via the ctypes pointer type cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works (I just tried):

```
p = pointer(f)
```

no need to instantiate P at all.
To be clearer, given the p and P look quite similar on screen:

```
from ctypes import *

class File(Structure):
 _fields_ = [("fileSize", c_uint),
            ("fileName", c_byte * 32)]

f = File()
f.fileSize = 2
print(f.fileSize)
p = pointer(f)
print(p.contents.fileSize)
```

Comment: What if I want to do pointer arithmetic and then dereference?