# ctypes: creating a pointer to a structure TypeError: unhashable type

Tags: python, ctypes

When I run this code, I receive a `TypeError: unhashable type`.

```
class FK(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Handle", ctypes.c_void_p),
                ("Status", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("Device", ctypes.c_ulong)]

f = FK()
fp = ctypes.POINTER(f)
```

error message:

```
fp = ctypes.POINTER(f)

TypeError: unhashable type
```

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284630/python-ctypes-and-pointer-to-structure) the code in the answer is similar.

Why is this an unhashable type and how can I resolve this?

Comment: You are confusing a pointer *type* with a pointer *of* that type. `POINTER` creates a pointer *type* (in your case it would be `POINTER(FK)` note the caps for the type of a pointer to that struct), but `pointer` will create an actual pointer. See the documentation [for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.pointer) each [one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.POINTER)

Comment: @JaredSmith you were right, I was confusing the pointer type with the pointer of that type. Changing POINTER to pointer solved my problem. Thanks for your help.